# How to force cockpit refresh of network changes via CLI

Tags: cockpit

When I make some scripted network changes such as these:

```
sudo nmcli con mod ens21 ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.20/24
sudo nmcli con mod ens21 ipv4.gateway 192.168.2.1
sudo nmcli con mod ens21 ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
sudo nmcli con mod ens21 ipv4.method manual
```

The network details in the cockpit Networking console are not updated with the new details.
[image]

If I click on the NIC in that view the changes are however correct.

[image]

How can I trigger a refresh of the main networking display?

I am using Rocky Linux 8.5 (which is RHEL 8.5).
About > Web Console returns cockpit version 251.1.